# Getting SyntaxError while using pdfcrowd with python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn pdfcrowd with Python 3.4, so I checked out their website and copied the following example:

```
import pdfcrowd

try:
    # create an API client instance
    client = pdfcrowd.Client("username", "apikey")

    # convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a pdf variable
    pdf = client.convertURI('http://www.google.com')

    # convert an HTML string and save the result to a file
    output_file = open('html.pdf', 'wb')
    html="<head></head><body>My HTML Layout</body>"
    client.convertHtml(html, output_file)
    output_file.close()

    # convert an HTML file
    output_file = open('file.pdf', 'wb')
    client.convertFile('/path/to/MyLayout.html', output_file)
    output_file.close()

except pdfcrowd.Error, why:
    print('Failed: {}'.format(why))
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
File "pf.py" line 21
   except pdfcrowd.Error, why:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: The example was likely meant to be ran on Python 2, not Python 3. That line is not valid Python 3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

That means to assign the error to the variable `why`.  That is valid syntax in Python2, but not in Python3.  Use `except pdfcrowd.Error as why:` instead.  That is valid syntax in Python2 *and* Python3

Comment: Is pdfcrowd meant to be used only with python2.x, because I saw that syntax in the pdfcrowd.py file as well.

Comment: From their [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfcrowd/), it looks like it.  You could use `py2to3` to convert it, though.